# pandas subtract rows in dataframe according to a few columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
data = [
 {'col1': 11, 'col2': 111, 'col3': 1111},
 {'col1': 22, 'col2': 222, 'col3': 2222},
 {'col1': 33, 'col2': 333, 'col3': 3333},
 {'col1': 44, 'col2': 444, 'col3': 4444}
]
```

and the following list:

```
lst = [(11, 111), (22, 222), (99, 999)]
```

I would like to get out of my data only rows that col1 and col2 do not exist in the lst

result for above example would be:

```
[
 {'col1': 33, 'col2': 333, 'col3': 3333},
 {'col1': 44, 'col2': 444, 'col3': 4444}
]
```

how can I achieve that?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

list_df = pd.DataFrame(lst)

# command like ??
# df.subtract(list_df)
```

Comment: Do you need test in pairs or each column separately?

Answer (score 2):

If need test by pairs is possible compare `MultiIndex` created by both columns in [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) with inverted mask by `~` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[~df.set_index(['col1','col2']).index.isin(lst)]
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3
2    33   333  3333
3    44   444  4444
```

Or with left join by [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) with indicator parameter:

```
m = df.merge(list_df, 
             left_on=['col1','col2'],
             right_on=[0,1], 
             indicator=True, 
             how='left')['_merge'].eq('left_only')
df = df[mask]
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3
2    33   333  3333
3    44   444  4444
```

Comment: Happy to see so many various answers :) +1 to all

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the list of values using `zip` and slice using a mask generated with [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html):

```
a,b = zip(*lst)
data[~(data['col1'].isin(a)|data['col2'].isin(b))]
```

output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
2    33   333  3333
3    44   444  4444
```

Or if you need both conditions to be true to drop:

```
data[~(data['col1'].isin(a)&data['col2'].isin(b))]
```

NB. if you have many columns, you can automate the process:

```
mask = sum(data[col].isin(v) for col,v in zip(data, zip(*lst))).eq(0)
df[mask]
```

Comment: Yes, your answer working different like all another, testing each column separately. I guess OP need test in pairs.

Comment: @jezrael mine works with both possibilities, on just need to use `|` or `&`, but I guess the example is ambiguous

Comment: I think `lst = [(11, 999), (22, 222), (99, 111)]` return differnt ouputs

Comment: because not tested in pairs in your solution.

Comment: I see what you mean, well as I said, difficult to interpret without the detils

Comment: I think we used a different vocabulary

Comment: ya, it is OK.  First it seems `data[~(data['col1'].isin(a)&data['col2'].isin(b)` is equivalent by all another answers.

Comment: mozway, @jezrael  Try adding a row `{'col1': 11, 'col2': 222, 'col3': 9999}` to the dataframe and you will see the difference.  `11` is in  `a` `(11, 22, 99)` and `222` is in `b` `(111, 222, 999)`.  You will get both the `|` and `&` options, i.e. `(data['col1'].isin(a)|data['col2'].isin(b))` and `(data['col1'].isin(a)&data['col2'].isin(b))` both True even though `(11, 222)` is NOT in `lst`.  The final output will drop this new row with both `|` and `&` options while other answers will keep this new row.   So, it depends on whether the tuples in `lst` are to be compared in whole or in parts.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a tuple out of your col1 and col2 columns and then check if those tuples are in the lst list. Then drop the fines with True values.

```
df.drop(df.apply(lambda x: (x['col1'], x['col2']), axis =1)
          .isin(lst)
          .loc[lambda x: x==True]
          .index)
```

With this solution you don't even have to make the second list a dataframe

Comment: Happy to see so many various answers :) +1 to all

Answer (score 1):

You can create the tuples of `col1` and `col2` by [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `tuple`.  Then test these tuples whether in `lst` by [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) (add `~` for the negation/opposite condition).

Finally, locate the rows with [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), as follows:

```
df.loc[~df[['col1', 'col2']].apply(tuple, axis=1).isin(lst)]
```

Result:

```
   col1  col2  col3
2    33   333  3333
3    44   444  4444
```

Comment: Happy to see so many various answers :) +1 to all

Answer (score 0):

use polars's anti join:

```
df1.join(pl.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=["col1","col2"]))
         ,on=["col1","col2"],how="anti").to_pandas()
```

Result:

```
   col1  col2  col3
2    33   333  3333
3    44   444  4444
```